# Update a PrimeFaces component after every ajax action

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

How can I have a PrimeFaces component, e.g. a `p:commandButton`, getting updated after every ajax function in the page? I need something that would work with a complex html, with lots of forms, dialogs etc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this is what you are looking for

```
<p:outputPanel autoUpdate="true">
    <p:commandButton ... />
</p:outputPanel>
```

Comment: Primefaces 7.0 dropped the attribute and added an element <p:autoUpdate /> that you can add to a child of other components.